# get a latest record in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Here is my Table

```
Select ClaimId
,InterestSubsidyClaimId
,BankId,BankName
,UpdatedPrincipalAmountofOutStanding
,[date] 

From InterestSubsidyReviseClaim 

Where IsActive = 1 and InterestSubsidyReviseClaim.InterestSubsidyClaimId=1
```

that gives me result like [image: gggggg]

now i want record number 3 and 10 only

and i only have "InterestSubsidyClaimId"

resulting record should be

[image: trytt]

so how it can be done????

Comment: i mentioned that i can only pass InterestSubsidyClaimId so there is no scope of claimID

Comment: Yes, I get it. Could you try the example I have provided below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved it by my self

```
Select ClaimId
,InterestSubsidyClaimId
,BankId,BankName
,UpdatedPrincipalAmountofOutStanding
,[date] 

From InterestSubsidyReviseClaim 

Where ClaimId=(

                   Select max(ClaimId)
                   From InterestSubsidyReviseClaim 
                   Where IsActive = 1 and InterestSubsidyReviseClaim.InterestSubsidyClaimId=1 
                   group by BankId

              )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. For example:

```
;WITH DataSource AS
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BankName ORDER BY ClaimID DESC) AS [RowID]
          ,ClaimId
          ,InterestSubsidyClaimId
          ,BankId,BankName
          ,UpdatedPrincipalAmountofOutStanding
          ,[date] 
    From InterestSubsidyReviseClaim 
    Where IsActive = 1 and InterestSubsidyReviseClaim.InterestSubsidyClaimId=1 
)
SELECT ClaimId
      ,InterestSubsidyClaimId
      ,BankId,BankName
      ,UpdatedPrincipalAmountofOutStanding
      ,[date]
FROM DataSource
WHERE [RowID] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select ClaimId
 ,InterestSubsidyClaimId
 ,BankId,BankName
 ,UpdatedPrincipalAmountofOutStanding
 ,[date] 
From InterestSubsidyReviseClaim a
Where IsActive = 1 and InterestSubsidyReviseClaim.InterestSubsidyClaimId = 1
and exists (    
    select max(ClaimId)
    From InterestSubsidyReviseClaim b
    Where IsActive = 1 and InterestSubsidyReviseClaim.InterestSubsidyClaimId = 1
    group by BankId
    having max(claimid) = a.claimId
    )
```